# How to add a Column Value, When Two Columns values are same in DATATABLE

Tags: datatables

i have a datatable Like

### Id    RetailPrice   Qty

1111    100     2
2222    50      4
1111    100     2
2222    100     2
3333    200     2

i need Output Like base on Same 'Id' and 'RetailPrice' columns.
i.e.
Code    RP  Qty
1111    100 4
1111    50  2
2222    100 2
2222    50  4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

var result = (from p in dtReport.AsEnumerable()
                              group p by new
                              {
                                  Id = p.Field("Id"),
                                  Price = p.Field("Price"),

```
                          } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              Id= g.Key.Id,
                              Price = g.Key.Price,
                              Qty = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x["PhysicalStock"].ToString()))
                          }).ToList();
```